# cuando publico/compilo/recompilo un modulo (proyecto) de mi solución en Visual Studio, el almacenamiento en el disco C: se incrementa

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, almacenamiento

Tengo un problema con una aplicación que estoy implementando.

Primero cuando el código me llego (la solución esta en el disco D:), este pesaba solo unas **7GB** aproximadamente, pero cuando hice la primera compilación se descargaron sus librerías y llego a pesar **27 GB**, lo cual yo lo veo normal por la descarga de sus librerías `NuGet` y todo ello.

Pero el problema es que incrementa el espacio en el `disco C:` llegando a incluso llenarlo, una solución es que le de a limpiar la solución y el espacio se libera, pero aun así no se libera todo el espacio que es usado, y eso suele suceder con `Compilación/Recopilación/Publicación`, por ello no se si es normal y debería tener un disco mas grande para que la aplicación lo use o si se debería configurar algo en el `IDE` para que ya no use tanto almacenamiento en el disco principal.

Comment: Nuget por ejemplo utiliza el disco C para guardar los paquetes que bajo y no tener que volver a bajarlos, como hace npm y otros manejadores de paquetes... pero lo raro es que haga lo mismo al compilar.. no deberia ir a C... pero, como hay cosas magicas, habria que ver tu proyecto en particular... igual un paquete de 7 GB es una barbaridad...

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas un programa como [WizTree](https://diskanalyzer.com/) para identificar qué carpetas están ocupando mucho espacio?

Comment: Edita la pregunta, agrega la versión de Visual Studio que estás utilizando, detalla los nugets que estás utilizando y cualquier otra cosa que permita a cualquier usuario reproducir tu escenario. Saludos.